# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type , but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error when trying to view my index view:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[GRCWebApp.Models.MembershipType]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[GRCWebApp.ViewModels.ListMembershipTypeViewModel]'.

The Controller is:

```
        public ActionResult ListClubMembershipType(ListMembershipTypeViewModel model, int clubId)
    {
        var types = from s in db.MembershipTypes
                    where (s.ClubId == clubId)
                    orderby s.Type
                    select s;
        return View(types.ToList());
    }
```

And the view model is:

```
    public class ListMembershipTypeViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Type")]
    public String Type { get; set; }

    public int ClubId { get; set; }
}
```

The view is:

```
@model IEnumerable<GRCWebApp.ViewModels.ListMembershipTypeViewModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Club Membership Types";
}

<h2>Club Membership Types</h2>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>

@Html.Partial("AddClubMembershipType")
```

Comment: Can you show the full details of the message (it should display the actual types) And does `db.MembershipTypes` return a collection of `ListMembershipTypeViewModel`? The naming suggests it will be returning `IEnumerable<MembershipType>`

Comment: Please check if you have complete error message - "of type ''" looks strange - I'd expect some reasonable type there (and for `IEnumerable`...)

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GRCWebApp.Models.MembershipType]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GRCWebApp.ViewModels.ListMembershipTypeViewModel]'.

Comment: Can you try this: `return View(types.AsEnumerable());` ?

Comment: Slightly different error after changing that                                The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[GRCWebApp.Models.MembershipType]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GRCWebApp.ViewModels.ListMembershipTypeViewModel]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is passing `List<MembershipType>` to the view, but the view expects `IEnumerable<ListMembershipTyp‌​eViewModel>`

Change you GET method to

```
public ActionResult ListClubMembershipType(int clubId)
{

  var types = from s in db.MembershipTypes
              where (s.ClubId == clubId)
              orderby s.Type
              select s;
  var model = types.Select(t => new ListMembershipTyp‌​eViewModel
  {
    Type = t.Type,
    ClubId = clubId
  });
  return View(model);    
}
```

Side note: Your method should not include the parameter `ListMembershipTypeViewModel model`

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to pass to the view and the view model are 2 different types, cast the entity bing brought from the database to an object of type :

```
ListMembershipTypeViewModel
```

You trying to pass it a List of MembershipTypes

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I overcame this type of error by following the below syntax of code, changed to the question scenario for clarification.

```
Public ActionResult ListClubMembershipType(int clubId)
{
  List<MembershipTypeViewModel> types = db.MembershipTypes.Where(s=>s.ClubId == 
  clubId).OrderBy(s=>s.Type).ToList();
  return View(types);
}
```

In scenario's where you need to find only single Member out of Many:

```
List<MembershipTypeViewModel> types = db.MembershipTypes.Where(s=>s.ClubId == 
clubId).Take(1).ToList();
```